# location.href Asp.net MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to redirect user to my another controller when he'll click in my div (which is picture). 
here's my Home Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Rules()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and of course they has their views..

In Index.cshtml I'm trying this:

```
 $("#rules").on('click', function () {
            var url = '@Url.Action("Rules", "Home")';
            location.href = url;
        });
```

How I think after click on rules div browser must be redirectedin my Rules.cshtml but it's doing that: https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t31.0-8/10515357_776619705702730_572107523657856972_o.jpg

but I have Home controller and Rules action.. what am I doing wrong?

I have tried this too:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Rules", "Home")">
            <div id="rules"></div>
        </a>
```

but same result.. I think something is wrong with controller but..? When I'm clicking "Go To View" there's no problem Visual studio is redirecting me to my view..

Comment: maybe you can try using non-razor binding in javascript: `var url = '@Url.Action("Rules", "Home")';` => `var url = '<%= Url.Action("Rules", "Home") %>';` ; and your url at the end seems to be ok from my side cause it reverse action a with b in url

Comment: Why do you need to use javascript? can you not just use a link?

Comment: Try building your project.

Comment: Do you have a specific route in your route config?

Comment: @Tobias when I'm building "========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped =========="... :\

Comment: @markpsmith other what can i do?

Comment: @NachoLaborde nope. it's default route config

Comment: @HellBaby same result..

Comment: When you right click your browser window and select 'View/show source code...', what does your anchor tag around your image look like (for the more simple 2nd example)?

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips 
"       <div id="rules"></div>"
and using css it's image

Comment: What about the anchor tag? e.g. <a href="...">

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips in that div i have not anchor tag. here all what i have:
<div id="rules"></div>
#rules {
    background-image: url('../Photos/wesebi.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 44px;
    width: 115px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 22px;
    margin-top: 23px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

and i'm trying to redirect using this:
$("#rules").on('click', function () {
                var url = '@Url.Action("Rules", "Home")';
                location.href = url;
            });

Comment: If you're going with the first example, then what does the rendered URL look like when you view the page source?

Comment: @AdrianThompsonPhillips $("#rules").on('click', function () {
                var url = '/Home/Rules';
                location.href = url;
            });

Comment: make sure you are adding the onclick event after the page loads completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why this wouldn't work:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Rules")"><div>image</div></a>
```

If you're redirecting to the same controller you only need to specify the action name.

If something as simple as this doesn't work then I suspect you've got something in your route values which is preventing it from working. Or maybe there's another problem, are you using areas for example?

Comment: I have tried your code but same result.. No i'm not using anything. simply MVC without anything. routing default, everything defauls.. What do u think what I must try to realize what's wrong with that?

Comment: I'm guessing you got it sorted - what was the problem?

Comment: visual studio :| he didn't recognised controllers. when i right clicked on project and than did clear after that everything is okay. but your code helped me because i marked him as good answer